# MySQL geospatial query - return nearest row

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial, database-performance

I have a table with the following structure:

```
id | code | coordinates
```

The ID is the primary key, code is something our internal application uses and the coordinates column is the **point** data type.

I need to construct a query that will quickly return the nearest row to a set of coordinates.

For example, if I gave the coordinates 50.8, -1.3 I would expect the query to return the nearest row as quick as possible (or at least faster than my attempt below).

Here is my attempt. I would use it but it takes 0.5 seconds to return the result.

```
SELECT localities.code
  FROM (
    SELECT glength(LineStringFromWKB( 
            LineString( 
            GeomFromText(astext(coordinates)), 
            GeomFromText(astext( PointFromWKB(POINT(663.422238,10.398996)))))))
      AS distance, code  
FROM locality
) localities
ORDER BY localities.distance ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Can anyone construct a query that will return results faster than this taking advantage of geospatial extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a bit of redundancy in your expression for selecting the distance.

I believe you can use

```
glength(LineString(coordinates,POINT(663.422238,10.398996))) AS distance
```

rather than what you have. That might help a bit with performance, but it won't help much.

The query as constructed performs a full table scan on your `locality` table to compute each distance. It then orders the results by distance and returns the first one.

If you don't have any apriori knowledge of the geometry in question it is hard to do better than that.  But if you can place a bounding box around your sample point and restrict your search to the bounding box, then you can use a `SPATIAL` index to speed things up a lot.

To use a `SPATIAL` index you need to be using a MyISAM access method on your table (InnoDB won't work). Then create the index on your `coordinates` column.

Then you need to work out the suitable bounding box.  Let's say you want to exclude any points at a distance more than 50 from your candidate `POINT(663.422238,10.398996)`.

What you need to do is this:

First, make a geometric object that's a diagonal line going across your bounding box, like so:

```
GeomFromText(
   CONCAT('LINESTRING(',
          663.422238 - 50,' ', 10.398996 - 50, ',',
          663.422238 + 50,' ', 10.398996 + 50, ')'))
```

Then use that geometric object with the SPATIAL-index exploiting function `MBRContains()` (minimum bounding rectangle contains) in a query like this.

```
SELECT localities.code
  FROM (
     SELECT glength(LineString(coordinates,POINT(663.422238,10.398996))) AS distance,
            code 
       FROM locality
      WHERE  MBRContains(
                GeomFromText(
                       CONCAT('LINESTRING(',
                               663.422238 - 50,' ', 10.398996 - 50, ',',
                               663.422238 + 50,' ', 10.398996 + 50, ')')),
                coordinates )
       ) AS localities
ORDER BY localities.distance ASC
LIMIT 1
```

The key is the bounding box. This way of running the query saves time by using the spatial index to choose a hopefully very small subset of the rows in the table to consider.

I wrote this up in some detail for lat/long work here. http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/using-mysqls-geospatial-extension-location-finder/

Note that it's sometimes a little fiddly to get the syntax of the GeomFromText stuff right. I hope it's right, but I might have misplaced a comma or something.

Comment: Thanks very much Ollie! Really appreciate your time putting this answer together for me.

Comment: Well I've been sat here for the last 15 minutes trying to tackle the fiddly syntax of `GeomFromText` myself. I'm stuck at "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM locality WHERE MBRContains ( GeomFromText( ' at line 5"

Comment: oops. Mysql doesn't allow spaces between function names and the parenthesis introducing the parameters. fixed.

Comment: Now I've got: "'FROM locality WHERE MBRContains(GeomFromText(CONCAT('LINESTRING(',663.42' at line 5", normally I'd be able to figure this out but as it's nearly 2AM in the morning my time I need to get some sleep, if you wouldn't mind correcting this for me then when I wake up I'll get working. Cheers :-)

Comment: looks like a missing paren. sorry about that. I hope you do your best to understand this stuff!